# How to get version value of package.json inside of Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

This is how my *Dockerfile* looks like: First I copy the files, then I run `npm install` and `npm build`. As you can see, I do set the productive ENV variable.

I would like to get the version of the current package.json file to the running docker image. So I thought of using en ENV variable, e.g. `VERSION`.

My package.json file could look like this:

```
"version": "0.0.1"
"scripts": {
     "version": "echo $npm_package_version"
}
```

So `npm run version` returns the version value. But I don't know how to use this result as ENV in my dockerfile

```
COPY . /app
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm run build

RUN VERSION=$(npm run version)

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV VERSION ???
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need the version from inside of your node app.. `require('./package.json').version` will do the trick.

Otherwise, since you're already building your own container, why not make it easier on yourself and install jq? Then you can run `VERSION=$(jq .version package.json -r)`.

Either way though, you cannot simply export a variable from a RUN command for use in another stage. There is a common workaround though:

```
FROM node:8-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add jq
COPY package.json .
COPY server.js .
RUN jq .version package.json -r > /root/version.txt
CMD VERSION=$(cat /root/version.txt) node server.js
```

Results from docker build & run:

```
{ NODE_VERSION: '8.11.1',
  YARN_VERSION: '1.5.1',
  HOSTNAME: 'xxxxx',
  SHLVL: '1',
  HOME: '/root',
  VERSION: '1.0.0',
  PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
  PWD: '/' }
```

Comment: `CMD ["VERSION=$(npm run version)", "node", "server.js"]` would not work? I do have to create the text file?

Comment: You absolutely should be able to do that. The creation of the text file was just one of the ways that you can cache it for multiple run steps.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply use `npm pkg get version` to retrieve the package version in the working directory.
in Dockerfile that's be something like that:

```
$(npm pkg get version)
```

or

```
RUN npm pkg get version
```

if you want other information from the package.json then change the version to any different key you want.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like:

```
COPY . /app
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm run build

RUN export VERSION=$(npm run version)

ENV NODE_ENV production
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using bash script (i.e. grep) in RUN command to read the value and set as environment variable. Docker will do a snapshot with the variable set and your good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you want the `package.json.version` in your app, e.g. in the log or in the healthcheck.

There are ways (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67545148) to include `package.json` using `resolveJsonModule` set to `true` in `tsconfig.json`, but after building, it might that the `package.json` is in a different location. Also you might get warnings that there is code (in this case `package.json` in the root) is not in the `./src` folder.

There are several ways to extract the `package.json.version`

1. If you use npm start to start the app, you can simply use `process.env.npm_package_version` in your code
2. If you don’t use npm start but node index.js you need to set the version in a custom environment variable:

- `npm pkg get version` - using npm (`npm pkg get version | xargs` or `npm pkg get version | tr -d \"` to strip the double quotes)
- `node -p "require('./package.json').version"` - using node
- `cat package.json | jq -r '.version'` - using cat and jq

Then you need to set this then in de Dockerfile , I’ve tried setting, but the environment variable doesn’t stick:

```
RUN export VERSION=$(npm pkg get version) # Doesn't work
RUN VERSION=$(npm pkg get version) # Doesn't work
```

The only way that it seems to work is setting it when the app starts, in the last line at the CMD command

in the Dockerfile  you set:

```
# Get the version from the package.json, strip the quotes and start the app
CMD VERSION=$(npm pkg get version | xargs) node index.js
```

and in the app you use the process.env.VERSION:

```
app.use('/health', (_req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ 
    status: 'OK', 
    uptime: process.uptime(), 
    version: process.env.VERSION 
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server version ${process.env.VERSION || 'unknown'} is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```