# How to pull application version (or import package.json file)? Google does not help :(

Tags: json, angular, typescript

In my Angular application, I'd like to display the version from the package.json file.

I know that to import it I need to allow importing json and for this tsconfig.json file needs to get a few extra lines:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {      
    "module": "commonjs",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

I did this, but after that when I import json file in my component class:

```
import { myPackage } from '../../../package.json';
```

I still get an error:

> Cannot find module '../../../package.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension.ts(2732)

And problem is not with path as I put another simple json file to the same folder but getting the same error.

I've googled and seen many examples that speak about '--resolveJsonModule', but it seems like I do all what's needed... but it still does not work.

I also restarted VScode and angular service - it did not help.

I use Angular 10.0.11 and TS 3.9.7

Please advise! Thanks!

Comment: have you checked out https://stackoverflow.com/a/48869478/6904274 it is working.

Comment: I read similar things many times, but THIS time it had an additional piece of information "(sometimes also necessary in /src/tsconfig.app.json)". Apparently, it is ONLY required it tsconfig.app.json. Thanks, deepak thomas! You saved my evening!!! If you post this as an answer, I'll be able to accept it.

Comment: It seems, like the reason I had to use 'app' version of tsconfig is that I also have a few other 'flavours': base, spec, and app. And each is responsible for own thing. Obviously, to have that import work in components under tests, I need to add it to 'spec' as well. But, better to just 'base'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deepak posted an almost proper answer, but for some reasons it did not work to me. Though, referenced answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48869478/6904274) has comments that actually helped.

In my case, the Angular application had more than just tsconfig.json, and to be able to import JSON files I had to modify other 'flavours': base, spec, and app. And each is responsible for their own thing. Obviously, to have that import work in components under tests, I need to add it to 'spec'. But, better to just 'base'.

Answer (score 16):

In order to access the package.json information in angular, you need to do 3 things

1. In your `tsconfig.json`, you need to enable `resolveJsonModule` option that is present in the `compilerOptions` like

```
    compilerOptions": {
         ......
         "resolveJsonModule": true
         ......
    }
```

2. After that, you can rerun `npm start` in your terminal.
3. Once you have rerun `npm start`, you will be able to access all the package.json variables inside the component as

```
import * as  packageJson from 'package.json';
......
export class AppComponent {
      ......
      version = packageJson.version;
      ......
}
```